# Custom field with Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, block

I would like customize my bootstrap email field but I feel like Twig doesn't take into account my customization.

1 - I do a dump to see the prefix of my block

```
"id" => "user_email"
"name" => "email"
"full_name" => "user[email]"
"disabled" => false
"label" => "Email"
"label_format" => null
"label_html" => false
"multipart" => false
"block_prefixes" => array:3 [▼
  0 => "form"
  1 => "text"
  2 => "_user_email"
]
"unique_block_prefix" => "_user_email"
```

2 - I call the theme at the top of Twig file

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

3 - Here it is my customize block

```
    {% block _user_email_widget %}
  {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="email">
    Email
  </label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      @
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Anything I write inside the block doesn't work.

If you have any tips to help me, I'll take it.

Thanks for you helping

Comment: did you clear your cache

Comment: I have clear the cache but same problem : it's doesn't work